# Copy to a variable range returns an error '438' Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy information from one sheet (labeled Testsheet), copy it to the next available empty row on the third sheet (Testsheet3), then rearrange the columns into what a third party considers a readable order and paste that rearranged selection onto the next available row on the second sheet (Testsheet 2).

I can't get my copied or cut selections to paste into my variable range.

I realize this isn't optimal because this is my first foray into coding. I'm not looking for a massive rewrite, as it is important that I understand edits made so that I can fix the macro in the future if I have to.

```vb
Sub BottleresorttestFinal()

'Probably reduntant
Sheets("Testsheet").Activate
'Remove selection from internal clipboard as it progresses
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Define my variable to find the last empty row for pasting
Dim NextEmptycell As Range

'Create an unsorted copy on a separate sheet
Sheets("Testsheet").Activate
Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("O2").End(xlDown)).Select
'I want the Macro to do nothing if there are no pasted selections below the O column
' since that will ALWAYS contain an integer is the row is populated
If ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Testsheet3").Activate
'Set the range of my variable to the next available empty row
Set NextEmptycell = Sheets("Testsheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
NextEmptycell.Select

ActiveSheet.Selection.Paste ''' This is where the error occurs

'Activate the correct sheet
Sheets("Testsheet").Activate
'Select the entire Bottles column below the Description bar
Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J2"), ActiveSheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Select
'Cut the selection
Selection.Cut
'Select the Cell to move the copied Cell next to (Cell 2, Item column)
Range("Store").Rows(2).Select
'Insert the selection to the right of Cell 2 in the "Items" column
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

'Select All below Row 1
Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row, 1)).Select
'Cut the data from "Testsheet, Row 2"
Selection.Cut
'Activate the destination worksheet "Testsheet2"
Sheets("Testsheet2").Activate
'Select the next empty cell for pasting
Set NextEmptycell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'Paste in the target destination "Row 2"
NextEmptycell.Select
ActiveSheet.Selection.Paste

'Activate the destination worksheet "Testsheet" to confirm that it is empty
' as it should be and ready for the next paste-in to be resorted
Sheets("Testsheet").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you indicate in your code where it stops behaving as expected? Try using `STOP` in your code to step through it and see where the line of code it stops working as expected. If you happen to already know, please indicate with a comment in the code where the issue line of code is.

Comment: Oh yes! Of course! I'm so sorry.

ActiveSheet.Selection.Paste is where the error message pops up. It pops up on the first instance of that string, but I imagine it'll do the same for the second instance of that same string near the bottom.

Comment: Always avoid `SELECT` statements. You can try `NextEmptycell.Paste`

Comment: Also, you can use backticks (next to the 1 on your keyboard) to `code block` in comments FYI

Comment: Every time you have a line ending in `SELECT` and another line doing something with selection, you can likely combine into one line (and should). Eg: `Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J2"), ActiveSheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Cut`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Hope you had a nice weekend. I tried to simplify it down but im getting the same error. Ive removed the dim variable entirely, since it seemed redundant. It now looks like this;

Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A"), ActiveSheet.Range(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Paste

Comment: The main party breaker is the named range `Store`. Please explain its purpose. Also, it is unclear where you are rearranging any columns. Are there any formulas or are there only values? Also, clarify where you need to paste any formatting. Could you post the images of all three worksheets with the desired results (hide columns `B:I`)? I understand that the columns `A:O` in `Testsheet1` should be empty after the code has run.